# Postgres using MAX operator

Tags: postgresql, max

I have a schema , where u have a Travel table, People table and a ClientTravel table that references both the Travel table and People Table.
I want to do the query that gives me the Client(s) that made the most travels in a year.

I've done a subquery that gives me the count of times a ClientId appeared in the ClientTravel Table like so:

```
SELECT cv.idpessoa , count(cv.idpessoa) as noviagens 
FROM viagem v , clienteviagem cv ,pessoa p 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.dtviagem)=2021 and v.idsistema = cv.viagem and p.id =cv.idpessoa 
GROUP BY cv.idpessoa
```

i Would like to do another query that uses the result of the previous one where it only gives me the PeopleId with the max Count.

I've managed to do a table that looks like this:

| idpessoa | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 |
| 5431 | 1 |
| 1242 | 3 |
| 8567 | 5 |

And now i want to retrieve a table like this :

| idpessoa |
| --- |
| 1234 |

Find the idpessoa that has the max value of count.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You can order by the count, then limit the result to one row:

```
SELECT cv.idpessoa , count(cv.idpessoa) as noviagens 
FROM viagem v 
  JOIN clienteviagem cv ON v.idsistema = cv.viagem
  JOIN pessoa p ON p.id = cv.idpessoa 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.dtviagem) = 2021
GROUP BY cv.idpessoa
ORDER BY count(cv.idpessoa) desc
LIMIT 1
```

If you have multiple rows with the same highest count, this will only return one of them. If you want to see all of them you can use:

```
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

instead of `limit 1`

---

This *can* be done using the max() aggregate, but it means you don't get to see the other column from the result:

```
select max(noviagens)
from (
  SELECT cv.idpessoa , count(cv.idpessoa) as noviagens 
  FROM viagem v 
    JOIN clienteviagem cv ON v.idsistema = cv.viagem
    JOIN pessoa p ON p.id = cv.idpessoa 
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.dtviagem) = 2021
  GROUP BY cv.idpessoa
) t
```

---

Another option is to use `max()` as a window function:

```
select cv.idpessoa, noviagens
from (
  SELECT cv.idpessoa, 
         count(cv.idpessoa) as noviagens,
         max(count(cv.idpessoa)) over () as max_noviagens
  FROM viagem v 
    JOIN clienteviagem cv ON v.idsistema = cv.viagem
    JOIN pessoa p ON p.id = cv.idpessoa 
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.dtviagem) = 2021
  GROUP BY cv.idpessoa
) t
where noviagens = max_noviagens;
```

Comment: But do u think theres a way u can work with max here?